# Content Types in Select list using views

Tags: nodes

How do I put all my content types into a select list so when users select a content type, they are taking to a page which makes them add new node to the content type?

Answer (score 1):

I think You can create exposed filter **Content: Type** which will give users  the ability to select content type.

Then in *Fields* section add field **Content: Type**, select "Output this field as a link" and type: node/add/[type].

If You want to display only one "add" link per content type select "Exclude from display", go to **Format** settings and select "Content: Type" from **Grouping field Nr.1**'s options.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use views? Simply use [node_types_get_names()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_names/7) to fill a select list on a form or pass items on a page as a themed list.